# Why is my import of the containsString method not working?

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

I've written the simple Java script below in order to learn more about TDD, IntelliJ and Java itself.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.both;

public class JUnit_Dummy {

  private StringJoiner joiner;
  private List<String> strings;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    joiner = new StringJoiner();
  }
....

  @Test
  public void shouldContainBothStringsWhenListIsTwoStrings() {
    strings.add("one");
    strings.add("two");
    assertThat(joiner.join(strings),
        both(containsString("A")).
            and(containsString("B")));
  }

}
_____________

import java.util.List;

public class StringJoiner {
  public String join(List<String> strings) {
    if(strings.size() > 0) {
      return (strings.get(0);
    }
    return "";
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use the "containsString" method inside an assertion, but IntelliJ keeps telling me that it "cannot resolve method 'containsString(java.lang.String)".  This despite the fact that the jUnit docs ([http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/matchers/JUnitMatchers.html#containsString(java.lang.String)](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/matchers/JUnitMatchers.html#containsString%28java.lang.String%29)) tell me that this method does accept a String parameter.

I've tried swapping out various import statements, including the following:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matcher.containsString;
import static org.hamcrest.Matcher.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
```

The best that I get is a greyed-out import statement telling me that the import statement is unused.  Not sure what the problem is, any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

Here is the exact compiler error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method containsString(java.lang.String)
  location: class JUnit_Dummy
```

Comment: Please provide the exact compiler error and/or stacktrace where you can see this.

Comment: Added.  But fwiw, as an IDE, IntelliJ is able to tell me that it can't resolve the method in question without me having to compile it.

Comment: JUnitMatchers or CoreMatchers?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis good question.  I thought I had tried both, but I just tried the following and it worked: 

    "import static org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.*;"

Thanks for the inspiration. :-)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, do you know why JUnitMatchers would work and CoreMatchers won't?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I thought I had tried every worthwhile import statement already, but this one did the trick:

```
import static org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.*;
```

Comment: I think you should use `org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString` since your import is officially deprecated (note the `s` in `Matchers`). But I noticed that there is also `org.junit.internal.matchers.StringContains.containsString` and `org.hamcrest.core.StringContains.containsString` so I'm wondering what's the most canonical import to use. Maybe somebody has an answer?

Comment: While this import does fix the issue, but the question remains "why?"

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue with a Spring Boot app.
Seems like this is a dependency ordering issue.. one of the dependencies mentioned in pom.xml before the "spring-boot-starter-test" artifact was overriding the hamcrest version.

So all I did was change the order (moved this dependency up):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.7.RELEASE.

Comment: Same with Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

We are supposed to use `containsString` method of hamcrest library.

My suggestion would be to stick to Junit 4 and import hamcrest library 1.3 in your build path. This would do the trick.

This will allow you to access other features of hamcrest library as well.

The solution can also be found by adding the required static imports manually. Or you can configure the required static imports in favorites tab of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

> import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with MAVEN - doing a tutorial and I ran into this same issue.

I used the "import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;" solution and that failed.

So I then moved JUNIT to be first on the  list in the POM file - and that solved it.