# I can't import the containsString CoreMatcher from hamcrest

Tags: gradle, groovy, junit

I'm trying to do the following:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString

assertThat(myvar, containsString("string to check"))
```

Here are my dependencies. I need to support junit 4 and junit 5

```
  testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-all:+')
  testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-inline:+')
  // use junpiter
  testImplementation(platform('org.junit:junit-bom:+'))
  testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter')
  testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params')
  // AND junit 4 because I use a test framework that has a hard dependency on junit 4
  testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13")
  testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.2")
  // Trying to pull in latest hamcrest
  testImplementation('org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2')
```

The problem is in my class when I to `import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString` It appears to be using hamcrest 1.3 which does not have "containsString". Is it using 1.3 because junit 4 depends on this version of hamcrest?

Is what I'm trying to do impossible because I'm pulling in both junit 4 and jupiter?

## EDIT

In my editor it says it does not exist:
[image]

Using my IDE I can read its docs on my localhost: (http://localhost:63342/..../hamcrest-core-1.3-javadoc.jar/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html)

[image]

When trying to run it I get this error

```
No signature of method: src.myproject.MyClassTest.containsString() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [string to check]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: src.myproject.MyClassTest.containsString() ....
```

Per comments I can see now it looks like its using CoreMatchers from mockito for some reason:
[image]

## EDIT Solution

Per comments the issue was that CoreMatchers was coming from mockito. I have removed mockito as a dependency and deleted its jars and that fixed it.

But I still don't understand how/why this was happening. I hope a proper answer to my question will include an explanation of why CoreMatchers was being fetched from the wrong place.

Comment: "It appears to be using hamcrest 1.3 which does not have containsString. " - The javadocs at http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#containsString(java.lang.String) indicate that it does.  Are those incorrect?

Comment: hmm well I can't do `import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString`. Is my import wrong somehow?

Comment: No.  That import statement looks correct and works for me here.  I can't reproduce your problem locally using hamcrest 1.3 and it is a little surprising that your JUnit 4  is pulling in hamcrest 1.3.  Sorry that I cannot help.  Best of luck.

Comment: The project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/red888hamcrest uses that static import at https://github.com/jeffbrown/red888hamcrest/blob/335015931f542b876f47b587730119ff8ded766f/lib/src/test/groovy/red888hamcrest/LibraryTest.groovy#L5. I hope that project will help you troubleshoot. Best of luck!

Comment: "I can't import the latest version of hamcrest" - Is your intent to use the latest version? I am not sure if you are saying that you are not allowed to use the latest version, or if you are attempting to and it fails.

Comment: changed title to "I can't import the containsString CoreMatcher from hamcrest". Im convinced its a dep issue. Looks like this person had a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984756/why-is-my-import-of-the-containsstring-method-not-working

Comment: " Im convinced its a dep issue." - The question says you are using 1.3. Look at your dependency graph and verify that is what is actually being used. If `import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString` does not work, I expect you aren't using the version of that class which is provided by Hamcrest 1.3.  The method appears to exist in the bytecode.

Comment: "It appears to be using hamcrest 1.3 which does not have containsString." - Are you basing the claim that 1.3 does not have `containsString` on feedback you are getting from `groovyc`, from your editor, or from something else?

Comment: Added an edit that has more error info

Comment: If you click through the `CoreMatchers` class name in your source code, which .jar does IntelliJ navigate to?

Comment: AH HA! looks like mockito is the issue? Why would it be taking it from there and is it possible to not have it do that for specific imports? I don't want to break tests that use mockito stuff

Comment: "I hope a proper answer to my question will include an explanation of why CoreMatchers was being fetched from the wrong place." - If you can edit the project I created with changes to recreate the problem and submit a PR, I would be happy to investigate it.